# How to remove String from a ListOf Strings in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a `listOf` `Strings`

```
val help = listOf("a","b","c")
```

And want to remove `b` from the `list` but **not using index** because I will get **Strings randomly** like this

```
val help = listOf("c","a","b")
```

How to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us any attempt(s)?

Comment: Did you read the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the `List` using the condition *item does not equal "b"*, like…

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // example list
    val help = listOf("a","b","c")
    // item to be dropped / removed
    val r = "b"
    // print state before
    println(help)
    // create a new list filtering the source
    val helped = help.filter { it != r }.toList()
    // print the result
    println(helped)
}
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c]
[a, c]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists by default aren't mutable. You should use mutable lists instead if you want that. Then you can simply do

```
val help = mutableListOf("a","b","c")
help.remove("b")
```

or you can do it like this if `help` really needs to be a non-mutable list

```
val help = listOf("a","b","c")
val newHelp = help.toMutableList().remove("b")
```

using a filter like in deHaar's answer is also possible